# Compare two string variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have two variables in sorted order.

`$a` contains

```
Gi1/1
Gi1/2
```

`$b` contains

```
Gi1/1
Gi1/2
Gi1/3
```

I tried to compare two variables whether it is equal or not equal as below:

```
if($a -eq $b) {
    write-host "equal"
} else {
    write-host "not equal"
}
```

but it didn't seem to work. The output should be "not equal", but it outputs as "equal". How can I fix this?

Comment: How are your `$a` and `$b` variables being declared?  You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: I agree with @TheIncorrigible1 - you need to update your question so it shows _how_ the two variables are being assigned. (Are you really sure they are `String` objects, for example?)

Comment: In the comment to the one answer, he says they're created using `Select-String` @Bill_Stewart

Comment: Understand - but the question is still incomplete IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have are two arrays (being returned from `Select-String`), but you're trying to do a string comparison.  When you do that, it's trying to do:

```
$a.ToString() == $b.ToString()
```

which is

```
"System.Object[]" == "System.Object[]"
```

---

A workaround, if the array only contains strings, is to concatenate them equally and then compare:

```
$a = @('Gi1/1', 'Gi1/2')
$b = @('Gi1/1', 'Gi1/2', 'Gi1/3')

if (($a -join '') -eq ($b -join '')) {
    'Equal'
}
else {
    'Not equal'
}
```